# Unable to import librosa

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, signal-processing, librosa

I did pip install librosa in Anaconda prompt. then uninstalled it, updated numba as i received outdated numba version error message. i installed librosa again still receiving this error while importing it. requesting help to import librosa!

[image: guvectorize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'signature']

Comment: Which versions of numba, resampy and librosa do you have?

Comment: Librosa: 0.9.2

Resampy: 0.4.0

numba: 0.50.1

Comment: Downvoting for using image when formatted text is preferred. Also, please add the versions to the body of the question, not as a comment. Use comments to alert users of updates to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the package code](https://github.com/bmcfee/resampy/blob/2ca177f53f60ce39317cb35a548c8c69c011b63c/setup.cfg#L42), `resampy` v0.4.0 requires `numba>=0.53`. Please ensure all your versions are consistent.